# How can I find historic volatilty for a stock?

Tags: options, implied-volatility

I sometimes read someone talking about an option's implied volatility being "high" or "low".  I assume this means in relation to the historic volatility, or some rough estimate of what it "usually is now adays".  I haven't had any luck finding the historic volatility for securities, and so don't have a way to decide whether or not IV for an option is higher than normal, lower than normal, incredibly high, etc.

Where do people without Bloomberg terminals go for historic volatility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brokers and web sites  calculate historic implied volatility in different ways so you'll see some variance in the numbers that each provides.  However, this isn't critical because there will be consistency at each location since the same formula will be used at that site. There are two sites that I use for reference.

The first is IVolatility.com which is free although you have to register.  They provide a page full of stats

Current 10, 20 and 30 day HV as the respective values one week ago, one month ago and the one year high/low.  They also provide a graph which allows a 3, 6 and 12 month view of puts, calls, or a combination.  Below is the 12 month composite for NFLX.

[image]

The other source is [McMillan's web site](https://www.optionstrategist.com/calculators/free-volatility-data) which provides weekly stats for Friday's close every Saturday (if they update in a timely fashion).  There are 4,000+ stock/ETF/Index symbols and stats include the 20, 50 and 100 day HV, the current IV, the percentile ranking of the IV and the underlying's price. NFLX would look like this:

```
Symbol  hv20  hv50  hv100  DATE   curiv  Days/Percentile  Close
NFLX     75    63    49   200409  43.15    600/ 67%ile    370.72
```

Comment: I read somewhere that the historic volatility is generally calculated using the previous year (365 days), I guess as a moving average.  That's not the case?

Comment: Historic volatility can be calculated for any period that you want.  Traditionally, historic volatility for the stock (not the historic implied volatility for the options of that stock) is based on standard deviation (one year).

Comment: I want to make a cautionary note here about IVolatility to anyone considering it (the site mentioned above).  The site was difficult to use and they sent newsletters to me with a broken unsubscribe link.  I asked them to remove me from their list and they refused to without also deleting the account.  I had them delete my account and they are still sending unsolicited newsletters (with broken unsubscribe link).

Comment: @horse hair - What's the big deal about an E-mail from IVolatility?  If you don't want to see it, identify it as spam and then delete when you do your periodic E-mail maintenance.

Comment: Bob it's literally the law in the US (CAN-SPAM act).  They are providing an unsubscribe link that doesn't work. Shady point number one.  They told me they wouldn't unsubscribe me without deleting my account essentially - shady point number two.  Not sure how you feel about privacy / security issues but this is very abnormal in both of those areas.